# How to show all records using PHP function and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, model-view-controller

I am new to mvc and I want to populate my table from database and I am having trouble with showing the data with the use of javascript to show it on my index. I am using a php function to query the sql script and i am using PDO.

index.php

```
   <tr>
    <th>last_name</th>
    <th>first_name</th>
    <th>middle_name</th>
    <th>gender</th>
    <th>age</th>
    <th>course</th>

  </tr>

   <tr> 
     <div id=content> </div
  </tr>
```

profile.php

```
    public function showProfileRecord(){

        require_once 'app/lib/config/config.php';

        $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT  a.`first_name`, a.`middle_name`, a.`last_name`,a.`gender`,a.`age`, a.`course` FROM account a ORDER BY name ASC");


        while ($rows = $result->fetch()) {

                $records = $records . "<td>" . $rows["last_name"] . "</td> <td>" . $rows["first_name"] . "</td> <td>" . $rows["middle_name"] . "</td>  <td>" . $rows["gender"] . "</td> <td>". $rows["age"] . "</td> <td>" . $rows["course"] . "</td>";     

}
    $returnData[]["records"] = $records;
    echo json_encode($returnData);
}
```

functions.js

```
   showProfileRecord = function(data){
   data = JSON.parse(data);

   $("#content").append("\
    <tr>" + data[0].records + "</tr>\
    ");
   }
```

Comment: why did you use those backslashes in js?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: did you get the data back in your js function ? please make sure this as well

Comment: @AbdulAhad no, i don't know how to get the data to the js function and show it to my index an error will occur if there is no backlashes

Comment: @u_mulder the js function won't work properly. My index table is still empty.

Comment: then i believe that, you can't do this. in your js function what you are doing, all depend on the data. If anyway you can't make sure if you get the data, then how are you going to except to index data in your table while it has no data to add to your table?

so please do some research and make sure that you have got the data by using `console.log(data)` in your js function like below

`showCalvingRecord = function(data){
   data = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log(data);
   $("#content").append("\
    <tr>" + data[0].records + "</tr>\
    ");
   }`

Comment: @AbdulAhad content still empty

Comment: do you know how to use console in js?